# Maintain a custom order/sort of documents in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

In my web app XY I'm showing a classic list/table of data (documents) to the user. While all the sort functions provided by MongoDB ( and Mongoose, i'm using Mongoose) are pretty clear to me, I'm not interested in sorting by date or alphabetical order. In my case it would be important to let the user maintain a custom sort as in manually drag/drop items around to set a specific order of the documents (e.g. putting favourites in top of the list ). The UI to do this is a no-brainer but how to actually save the order in the database, brain-freeze.

**Problem :** How would I go about saving such a custom order of documents ?

**What I use :** NodeJS / Express / Mongoose (MongoDB)

---

## Ideas

So far I could think of 2 ideas on how to do this.

- **A** : Having an additional key (e.g. `orderKey`) in the mongoose Schema. Big con : I would need to keep constantly updating all documents orderKeys. Also I would need some sort of auto-increment for new documents.

```js
const mySch = new Schema({
   orderKey : { type : Number }
});
```

- **B** : Creating one Schema/Model only for sorting, with an `Array` including all documents _ids for example. The order of the elements within the array would be used as reference for the custom order of the documents. Whenever the order changes, this `Array` would be changed as well.

```js
conts orderSch = new Schema({
   orderArray : { type : Array }
}); 
mongoose.model('Order', orderSch);

/* const customOrder = new Order({
   orderArray : [ _id1, _id2, _id3, _id10, _id7, .. ]
}); */
```

Any more ideas or best practises are highly appreciated !

Comment: I have found one solution custom mongorc.js which sorts the document keys by default for you. It's called [Mongo Hacker][1]


  [1]: http://tylerbrock.github.io/mongo-hacker/

Comment: @pawansgi92 Thanks for your suggestion. I took a quick look at this mongo-hacker tool but I don't think it's suitable if I want to have a custom order for each user or even subdocuments or references documents Also I'm looking for a solution on how to "store/save" the order. I'm not looking for a solution to sort documents.

Comment: @PascalLamers, what did you end up going with? I'm currently torn between these same 2 options. Were there any major drawbacks with the option you chose?

Comment: (1/3) In my particular use-case in the end it made more sense to keep an `orderKey` at document level. I have a group document (called `collection`) and many child documents (called `triggers`). Each `trigger` always has just one specific parent `collection`. This allowed me to keep the `orderKey` at document level, and that is the `trigger` documents in that case. In the UI, whenever a new `trigger` is created, I would first look for the first free available "position" inside the `collection` where the `trigger` is being created. Also this is used for a grid, so there are many empty positions

Comment: (2/3) When a position of one `trigger` is being updated, only this specific `trigger` gets updated in the database. There is no "swapping", so I don't have to update the position of multiple `trigger` at once. If I would implement "swapping" I would have to deal with updating multiple triggers at once.

Comment: (3/3) If I would deal with a list of items (not a grid), where "swapping" is a must-have feature I would go with option B, to keep an additional order seperately but specific to the list. The major drawback I could think of when using B is that the orderArray keeps growing - how big should/can it get ?

Comment:  I still feel there must be a better solution to this problem. But probably depends on the specific use-case ...