# how to update records after drag and drop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am using [react-sortable-hoc](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc) to drag/drop and reorder items. When I do this though I want to update the database (node.js and mongodb).

Firstly, I have changed it to be a functional component which is why my syntax looks a bit different to the example.

```
const onSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {

    setItems((items) => arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex));

    const newArray = arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex);

    async function makePatchRequest() {
      const config = {
        method: "patch",
        url: "http://localhost:8000/api/admin/faq/order",
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token },
        data: {
          order: newArray,
        },
      };

      let res = await axios(config, { order: newArray });

    }
    makePatchRequest();
  };
```

I am sending the new array to the backend with everything in the order after the drag and drop. The issue is that I don't really know what to do with it on the backend. Do I need to delete all records and then loop over the array and insert new records? I initially wanted to loop over the records and update them but it isn't actually doing anything, probably because the code is wrong or my logic is wrong because all it is doing is overwriting with the exact same data because all that has changed is the order of the array, not the actual id or _id in the array.

```
exports.faqSort = async (req, res) => {
  const { order } = req.body;
  console.log(order);

  await order.map((o) => {
    Faq.update({ _id: o._id }, { $set: { id: o.id } });
  });
};
```

This is the array when the page loads:

```
[
  {
    _id: '5ed273049b268308302cb1fb',
    question: 'question 1',
    answer: 'answer 1',
    id: 1,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5ed273439b268308302cb1fd',
    question: 'question 2',
    answer: 'answer 2',
    id: 2,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5ed276129b268308302cb1ff',
    question: 'quesiton 3',
    answer: 'answer 3',
    id: 3,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

And this is the new array I send to the backend

```
[
  {
    _id: '5ed276129b268308302cb1ff',
    question: 'quesiton 3',
    answer: 'answer 3',
    order: 3,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5ed273049b268308302cb1fb',
    question: 'question 1',
    answer: 'answer 1',
    order: 1,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5ed273439b268308302cb1fd',
    question: 'question 2',
    answer: 'answer 2',
    order: 2,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Comment: You want to store/maintain the custom order of the items in the database, right ? Like drag/drop a list of items and keep the order persistent. I have the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193436/maintain-a-custom-order-sort-of-documents-in-mongodb but haven't found any solution for it. Weird that I haven't found anyhting to it yet, for a problem I believe is very basic .

Comment: Yes, I have a column in the database for the order number ie: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. This is basically a sort order column, different to the primary key ID or the long mongo id you get when creating a new record. On the frontend I order by the sortorder but also trying to figure out the logic to persist the data after dragging and dropping.

Comment: How does your model look like ?

Comment: My model looks normal (mongoose) except I have an auto increment package so that I have have an auto incrementing number for my sort column. It's super easy to use and can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-sequence

Comment: Weird, just by looking at your code it should work. There is probably a special behaviour with the `Model.update` method. In comparison, have you tried retrieving (finding) the document first, updating the value and saving it again ? I know these are more steps, but would be interesting if you get the same results.

Comment: My code doesn't work because the ID's and all the data is exactly the same. Jus the order of the array is different. So, when I update, I am just updating 1 with 1, 2 with 2 etc. and not changing 1 to 2 or 2 to 1 etc. I found a way to update single record that am am actually dragging and dropping but then you have 2 records with the same sort order id. I will try to add some visual aid to the question to better explain

Comment: @PascalLamers, updated my question. So you can see the data is the same, just the order of the array is different, so updating the records in the backend doesn't actually change any data

Comment: Ah now I see. When you send the new array to the backend, your order key hasn't changed yet, just the order of the array. If that's the case you probably want to use the index of the array as new order key .

Comment: I can get the old order id and the new one and then update the old one with the new one in the database but then you have 2 duplicate records. It could get messy quickly... `const olditem = items[oldIndex];` `const newitem = items[newIndex];`

Comment: Why do we need to send the whole array to change the order? Can’t we just send the source and destination two ids and update their order for only these two ids? I think this is possible with unique index of order and the _id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you updating the documents, use the index values from the array to update the order id.

```js
const promises = order.map( async (o, index) => {

  let orderkey = index + 1;
  const promise = Faq.updateOne({ _id: o._id }, { $set: { order: orderkey } });

  return promise;

});

const results = await Promise.all(promises);
```

This way the `order` key will be updated based on the order of the array you are sending .

But think about actually updating the `order` key already in the frontend, before sending it to the backend. This way the order of the array wouldn't matter.

Comment: I am not sure if it works the same in the actual update and maybe that is why it isn't working, but if I console.log then the + 1 doesn't actually do the maths, it ends up making 0 = 01, 1 = 11, 2 = 21 EDIT: actually no, I manually updated the database values to start the order at 0 but still doesn't update. The console.log is showing correct data though eg:`question 3 0
question 1 1
question 2 2`

Comment: Ha that's weird . Last time I checked, `index` is Number. Adding another number to it should still give you a number. Then let's do the math before updating the doc. Updated my answer.

Comment: I am starting to believe that the `await` on Array.map is misplaced .

Comment: Something isn't quite right because the database isn't updating... even though the console.log is showing correctly

Comment: Do I not need to call save() using update in mongoose?

Comment: `Model.update` does not require to `save()` . `save` method is for Documents. I updated my answer again to fiddle a bit with the way you iterating over your array with an async function inside of it. If that still doesn't work, I would suggest first updating the documents one by one (like find the doc, update doc, save the doc) - and if it works you could refactor again using promises, etc.

Comment: Interesting, got this notice with your update. `collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.`

Comment: Changed to updateMany and it works! :) Still just taking a look at exactly what you changed and why its works etc. so I actually understand why

Comment: Ah that's quite interesting, we are getting somewhere ! I updated my answer to use `updateOne`

Comment: Great that we get somewhere ! Glad I could help with it :)

Comment: Thanks again, I hope it has helped you with your issue as well for your question that you linked to earlier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215020/discussion-between-pascal-lamers-and-user8463989).

Comment: I’d rather suggest to update only those two ids in the backend otherwise you will end up iterating the whole array of list in that column and that’s heavy operation to do so. Simply get source and destination item ids and change their order

Comment: This would be true if only 2 ids changed , like swapping item 17 with 18 - not if the order of multiple items in the list has changed. You will end up having multiple requests for each item you change the order of - on the other hand I think this is what OP is doing (sending request after each drag and drop event) so you're maybe right.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and safest way I think would just be to use "order" key in the objects held by the array. You could just keep the array in any order, instead using the "order" key to handle, well, the order.

You can always manipulate your array with the built-in `sort()` method, or query this the "order" key in Mongoose.

Basically, don't use the array's order, but your own instead.

Answer (score 0):

## `bulkWrite` is a good option

I encountered this kind of problem. As your data grows there will be a lot of operation happening for updating the order of the documents. instead of sending multiple trips to the server you can optimize it with `bulkwrite` as it will only send `1 single` trip to the server.

I am using `Nuxt` framework on this example but you will surely get the idea.

```js
try {
  const { ids } = await readBody(event)
  
  const bulkOps: any = []
  
  ids.map((id: string, index: number) => {
    const data = {
      updateOne: {
        filter: {
          _id: id
        },
        update: {
          order: index
        }
      }
    }
    return bulkOps.push(data)
  })
  
  await taskModel.bulkWrite(bulkOps)
  
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    statusMessage: 'success'
  }
  
} catch (error) {
  return errorResponse(500, 'Something went wrong.')
}
```

see [bulkwrite documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#definition)

Good 5 min video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHmbRQc1JX0)

I tested it and it works. Here is the sample.

[image]