# I want update whole array of results by new data in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

**I want to change or rearrange my DB data with the new array what i will be sent from client as a payload like {data: **newArray**}** actually i want to changed the index according to the newArray

Think i have a response like the below

```
{
    "message": "Home data fetched successfully",
    "success": true,
    "status": 200,
    "results": [
        {
            "_id": "64337b95bc5a14632cbda851",
            "name": "sds",
            "active": false,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "6433891ef830ca06db408966",
            "name": "hello_world",
            "active": false,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "6433891ef830ca06db408966",
            "name": "world_war",
            "active": false,
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "resultInfo": null
}
```

Now i want to the above data with **newArray** one like the below

```
[
        
        {
            "_id": "6433891ef830ca06db408966",
            "name": "hello_world",
            "active": false,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "64337b95bc5a14632cbda851",
            "name": "sds",
            "active": false,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "6433891ef830ca06db408966",
            "name": "world_war",
            "active": false,
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
```

my code is:

```
exports.dragandUpdate = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.body.author._id;
    const newData = req.body.data;


    const result = await homeModel.updateMany(
      { author: userId },
      { results: newData },
      { new: true}
    );

    res
      .status(200)
      .send(successHandler(200, result, "Data updated successfully"));

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(rejectHandler(500, null, error.message));
  }
}
```

But its not working please help me thanks and forgive me for bad english

Comment: Why do you want to update/replace all with new data? What do you mean by __i want to changed the index__?

Comment: think that i have 5 object in results and i have a features to reArrange the list item with drag in react so acccording to the changes i want to change the data into database (mongoDB) 
eg. which one was in index 4 that becomes in index 1 so accoring to the changes i want to change it into mongodb

Comment: I guess instead of replacing the whole data. It would be easier to have one more field something like sortOrder. So once your drag operation is done you just update the sortOrders and display data according to this sortOrder in frontend.

Comment: please give an example how sholud i achieve that things

Comment: I don't have any reference handy at this moment. But you can just google through some example/tutorial so that you will get some lead on how to proceed. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62113895/how-to-update-records-after-drag-and-drop